# Will detect thoughts work on a familiar, if the familiar is communicating telepathically with me?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, familiars

[Mind flayers](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/17104-mind-flayer) have captured our companions, and have some of our mcguffins, too.  So we're going after them.  They're kinda scary, especially if they have [intellect devourers](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/17163-intellect-devourer) with them, so we're trying to be super-stealthy.

I am thinking we can use *[flock of familiars](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/flock-of-familiars)* to scout way ahead of the party, and if the familiars are in the forms of bats, for instance, they have 2 intelligence and don't have a language, and are therefore not valid targets of *[detect thoughts](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/detect-thoughts)*.

However, I'll be communicating with the familiars telepathically.  Are the familiars still invalid targets, even though they are "communicating"?  It seems like they aren't, that they still don't have a language and still are only 2 smart, but I want to make sure I'm not missing anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Not to worry

**Intellect Devourers** do not have detect thoughts, they have

> **Detect Sentience**. The intellect devourer can sense the presence and location of any creature within 300 feet of it that has an Intelligence of 3 or higher

If your familiars have an intelligence of less then 3, then they would not be discoverable by this feature. There are no clauses that talk about telepathic communication changing this. However, the low intelligence of the familiars may limit what insights they can share telepathically with you (depending on how your DM handles this).

**Mind Flayers** themselves have *detect thoughts* proper, to use at will. It says

> You can also use this spell to detect the presence of thinking creatures you can’t see. (...) You can’t detect a creature with an Intelligence of 3 or lower or one that doesn’t speak any language.

So as long as your familiars have Intelligence 2 (and speak no language, to boot), they will not be affected. As above, there is no mention about telepathy influencing this. *You* are still not doing the thinking, the familiar is. Your mind has not replaced the familiar's mind, it is merely communicating with it.

Finally, Find Familiar says:

> Additionally, as an action, you can see through your familiar's eyes and hear what it hears until the start of your next turn, gaining the benefits of any Special Senses that the familiar has.

Also here, there is no indication that your mind is replacing the familiars' mind. You merely extend your sensory inputs to see through the familiar's eyes. Your mind and you yourself as a creature with a mind to be detected still hide out back where you are sitting tight. I think to affect you, one would need to rule that your mind has entered the familiar, and that would be stretching the interpretation of what the spell says beyond what the text supports.

Kudos to your DM for putting such fear of mind flayers into you. They surely are scary suckers. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The Mind Flayer combined with multiple Intellect Devourers is a particularly nasty combination.  The MF has a 60-ft cone INT save or be stunned, then once victims are stunned, the IDs move in and can use Body Thief the same round.  So in one round multiple members of the party can be not only incapacitated, but turned against the party. Gotta nuke 'em from orbit, it's the only way to be sure.